# WebStorm Error: Please specify path to JavaScript file correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm

I am using WebStorm on Windows to work on node.js projects.

Recently, when I open one of my projects that are located on the OneDrive directory I got the 'Error: Please specify path to JavaScript file correctly' when I run a .JS file. However if I move the same project folder to an other directory (Desktop for example) it works correctly.

PS: Nodemon keeps restarting forever when running on the onedrive project.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7619#comment=27-2504574 for possible workaround.
And, if possible, use some VCS for sharing instead of OneDrive, see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839.